Difference between the hotshoe on Canon EOS R7 and the one on Canon EF-mount cameras?
The EOS R7 manual states that the camera needs an adapter for some devices that use the hot shoe (GPS, the ST-E3-RT flash transmitter, and some flashes). As far as I can tell, comparing the R7 and the 70D, the contacts are the same, and the only visible difference is a slight "funnel" shape on the R7.
So where is the difference? As far as I can tell, the YN-ST-E3 transmitter (which is a knock-off of the ST-E3-RT) appear to work, despite what the manual would imply?

Only the weather sealing is not backwards compatible (same as the R3). If you want a sealed connection you need to use the AD-E1 adapter.

So the only purpose of the adapter is weather sealing?

@xenoid, yes; according to everything I've ever read/seen.

The adapter allows the weather sealing collars on the specific flashes and controllers listed with the statement in the R7 manual, such as the EL-1, 600EX II-RT, 600EX-RT, 580EX II, ST-E3-RT, or OC-E3 flash cord, all of which which have legacy hot feet sized weather sealing collars, to seal properly with the legacy sized hot shoe on top of the AD-E1 Adapter while the adapter seals properly with the camera's Multi-Function Hot Shoe. These flash/controller units have weather sealing rubber collars designed for the older legacy hot shoe and the rubber collars don't extend far enough forward to cover the extra data contacts on the front of the new Multi-Function hot Shoe.
One can use items such as the 600EX-RT and II-RT, EL-1, ST-E3-RT, etc. directly on the R7's hot shoe, but there will be no weather/dust resistant seal preventing moisture and dust from reaching the data contacts at the front of the Multi-Function Shoe. Even when no attachment is using the contacts, exposure to moisture may cause adjacent contacts to short out, possibly damaging the camera's circuitry.
One must also take care to not push flashes/controllers made for the legacy shoes too far into the newer Multi-Function Shoe. This could result in the main legacy pins not being properly aligned between the hot foot of the flash or controller and the camera's hot shoe. Instead one should carefully line the hot foot on the legacy flash/controller with the main pins on the Multi-Function Hot Shoe and set the locking mechanism. Some people find it easier to push the hot foot all the way in, then pull it back while gently pushing the lockdown lever (on items equipped with a lever instead of a "screw-down" type collar) until they feel it lined up.
Most other legacy flashes for Canon's EF hot shoe, including 3rd party ones, do not have weather sealing collars, or at least not to the extent of the listed flashes/controllers. But even then, by removing the hot shoe cover provided with the camera for when no flash or controller is mounted on the Multi-Function Hot Shoe and not placing a flash/accessory in the Multi-Function Hot Shoe that has weather sealing designed for use with the Multi-Function Hot Shoe, one is risking exposing the contacts to moisture and dust.
